# Pandas read_csv no lee bien lo datos de txt

Tags: python, pandas

tengo un archivo txt de 20 columnas, el cual no me reconoce los datos, uso el siguiente codigo:

```
df=pd.read_csv('MC01.txt', sep='\t')
```

la txt original es asi, esta separado por tabulador cada campo

---

```
No. Date    Time    Splice  Sequence    Error   Error-Text  Mode    C.Section   Width   Pres.   Amp.    >Energy CH-Product  CH-Ref-Product  WH-Product  WH-Ref-Product  t   t-Ref   p
1   25. ene 21  10:33:19    X02-G048.LA_5               Prod.   9.50    4.26    3.26    100 885 2.76    2.74    2.41    2.42    537 529 
2   25. ene 21  10:33:03    X02-G048.LA_5               Prod.   9.50    4.26    3.26    100 885 2.73    2.74    2.44    2.42    530 530 
3   25. ene 21  10:27:02    X02-G048.LA_5       209 ERROR: Medida de soldadura  Prod.   9.50    4.26    3.26    100 885 2.67    2.74    2.28    2.42    536 529 
4   25. ene 21  10:25:58    X02-G048.LA_5               Prod.   9.50    4.26    3.26    100 885 2.72    2.73    2.41    2.42    519 531
```

---

y me sale el siguiente error:

---

```
    N   Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  Unnamed: 10 Unnamed: 11 Unnamed: 12 Unnamed: 13 Unnamed: 14 Unnamed: 15 Unnamed: 16 Unnamed: 17 Unnamed: 18 Unnamed: 19
    0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Parece que  algunas columnas están separadas por más de una tabulación.

Comment: Propablemente sea un problema de encoding en una máquina windows. Habría que verificar que la codificación es utf-8. Se puede incluir la codificación al leer el archivo: `df=pd.read_csv('MC01.txt', sep='\t', encoding='UTF-16 LE')`

Comment: el encondig esta bien es UTF-8, en cuanto la tabulaciones solo tiene una por datos revise hasta la quinta fila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise sugerencia de Leonardo y el problema era en el enconding coloque lo siguiente:

```
df=pd.read_csv(path, encoding='UTF-16', sep='\t')
```